# Fix Sonar 'Trailing Comment' with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I would like to fix Sonar issue Trailing Comment.
How could I do this automatically for all code base?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you answer your own question as soon as you asked it? And what exactly does the answer do?

Comment: This is the way for me to backup usefull code snippets for me as company rules are quite strict, and I can't access to network shared resources ) Whenever anything fits stackoverflow idea, to rise concreate problem and to get concrete answer for it, I can post it here. This also may be usefull for the ocmmunity as it will appear in google search result at a time. I've done google search and find no concreat answer before the post.

Comment: well, in order to make it "more usefull", you may want to add some information about "what does the Trailing Comment" issue mean? 
add an example, and actually explain why it is answered by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Search `^([^\S\r\n]*)([^\s\r\n/"]+[^\r\n/"]*)[^\S\r\n/]*(//.+)$`
Replace with `$1$3\r\n$1$2`

Search `^([^\S\r\n]*)([^\s\r\n/"]+[^\r\n/]*;)[^\S\r\n/]*(//.+)$`
Replace with `$1$3\r\n$1$2`